# Web based code editor with auto completion

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, ace-editor

guys

I'm building the web based code editor for my personal project.I want to make it work like VS code but facing some issues.

I'm using ACE editor.

This is what I get while trying with autocompletion.

[image]

I'm getting all the available suggestions while trying to write "os.(something)", rather then just getting the language and package specific suggestions.

What I want is this.

[image]

In this pic as you can see I'm getting suggetion related to os package only.

Comment: there is [related issue](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3815). they suggest to have your own [language-server-protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your setup with require-js, you may also need to include an additional javascript file in the html for your page. You need to write this simple script to working with the auto completion feature.

```js
ace.require("ace/ext/language_tools");
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.setOptions({
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true
});
```

Demo: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/demo/autocompletion.html

Reference: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/How-to-enable-Autocomplete-in-the-Ace-editor

Comment: Thanks @ImBIOS, You'r answer seems more practical, 
I have already enabled the norm auto complete, Now I want to make my web based code editor work like desktop based code editor for auto completion.
It solves my query half way. I'm beginner with web based code editor. I don't know how to configure different json/js in-order to make it work properly for code editor.

Kindly provide more detailed approach.

Comment: You can update your question with several useful information so I can better understand and better deliver the solution that you need @AnandShrivastava

Answer (score 1):

HTML, JS, CSS Based

1. Create `<textarea onkeyup=compile() id=code>`. It should be big enaugt for code.
2. Create `<script> </script>`
3. Build the autocomplete
4. Script: `function compile() { document.GetElementById('code').value = document.GetElementById('code').value.replaceAll('snippet1', 'Snippet1Value').replaceAll('snippet2', 'SnippetValue'). ...`

E.g.: When you enter `_text_` (and you set `snippet1` to `<input type=text>`) then your textarea will write `<input type=text>`. To create an picker, use a contextmenu-library at json.

I know, this is only an plan how to do is.

Comment: Thanks for such a descriptive answer, This way we might end-up in some cluttered code!